# How to prevent output from '&' and '>' operator (send to background operator and redirection operator)

Tags: command-line, bash

I have tried various combinations of `gedit`, `&`, `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null`. When `gedit` is used with the other two it always prints something to the terminal.

[image: gedit in Terminal]

I understand that the numbers are pid's. But, please elucidate the following

- Why are those outputs produced when I redirected stdout and stderr to /dev/null, whereas bare `gedit` does print nothing?
- What does `[1]+ Done` mean?
- How to prevent those outputs?

Comment: If title is not appropriate, please change it to attract best answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 24446
$ 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 10
```

The `[1] 24446` and `[1]+  Done ...` are printed by the shell. From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1):

```
When  bash starts a job asynchronously (in the background), it prints a
line that looks like:

      [1] 25647
```

You can disable the `Done` output by disabling monitor mode:

```
set +m
```

You cannot disable the first form in an interactive shell, however. Instead, try running in a subshell:

```
$ (gedit &> /dev/null &)
$
```

if you use this, the background process is no longer under job control of the shell.

One a side note, `&>` can be used to redirect both stdout and stderr together.

Comment: Yes, `set +m` and then putting `gedit &> /dev/null &` inside `()` solved the issue. Can you please elaborate what is `()` operator, what its impacts are, and when to use it? I may need to accept your answer

Comment: @MAKZ Like I said, it starts a subshell. The implications of a subshell might be a bit too much for this answer. I suggest you read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell, and ask a question if you have trouble understanding it.