# Most efficient way of launching and separating a program from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I'm trying to launch a program from the Terminal in such a way that the following occurs:

1. Closing the Terminal does not close the program
2. The program is not outputting anything to the Terminal while opening, using, or closing
3. The Terminal is free to be used for other things
4. The command is short and sweet
5. There is no output file to worry about

Comment: Like always, if you find yourself frequently typing something long, make a shortcut for it using an alias, or  a shell function when an alias won't do the trick.

Comment: Try `screen -mdS xyz <command> &`.

Answer (score 15):

See `man nohup`:

```
NAME
   nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
```

Answer:

```
nohup program-name &
```

Comment: Almost what I'm looking for.   But, it still outputs to the screen when the program is opened and closed: [1]+  Done                    nohup google-chrome

Comment: @Evan , yes, you will get these messages, and i don't think there's any way around it, but otherwise it's the best way to separate terminal and the program, and it will be immune to closing the terminal window. Personally, I upvote this answer. Small suggestion , though, you can use `nohup program-name 2> /dev/null &` to also  redirect errors

Comment: @Evan that's not nohup, that's bash: http://askubuntu.com/a/590193/158442

Comment: The thing I hate about nohup: it doesn't understand aliases in zsh.

Answer (score 8):

I think this would be the most complete way:

```
program-name </dev/null &>/dev/null &
disown %%
```

Disowning the backgrounded process means the shell won't track it anymore. It won't tell you when it's done. It won't prevent you from closing your shell. `%%` means "the most recently backgrounded job".

If you want to hide all the details, put a function like this in your .bashrc

```
launch_and_forget () { "$@" </dev/null &>/dev/null & disown %%; }
```

Then

```
launch_and_forget program args "args args" ...
```

Give a name that's meaningful for you.

Comment: `<>/dev/null 1>&0 2>&0` is slightly shorter than `</dev/null &>/dev/null` and uses slightly less kernel memory.

Answer (score 6):

You can very simply use **`setsid`**:-

```
NAME
       setsid - run a program in a new session

SYNOPSIS
       setsid program [arg...]

DESCRIPTION
       setsid runs a program in a new session.
```

**Try the following command:-**

```
setsid <command>
```

Example:- `setsid gedit`, `setsid nautilus ~/Downloads/` etc.

Comment: This seems like the best answer to me, why would one use `nohup` over `setsid`?

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Use `tmux`.

First launch `tmux`, then run whatever command you want. You can close the `tmux` window, or drop back by shortcut `CTRL-B D`. In fact, you can even later reattach by `tmux attach`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), as [Siyuan Ren](https://askubuntu.com/a/609905/343983) suggested, or [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). That way, you get a new terminal for your command. You can detach it and forget about it, but you can get back if you change your mind.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up, and continue to use...

```
(nohup program-name 2>/dev/null &)
```